# Keyboard not showing after MFMessageComposeViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, keyboard

In an iPhone app I have a `UITextView` and a button, which lets the user send the content of the `UITextView` as a text message. The code looks like this:

```
MFMessageComposeViewController *picker = [[MFMessageComposeViewController alloc] init];
picker.messageComposeDelegate = self;

picker.body = textView.text;

[self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
```

Everything works fine, except for when the message is either sent or Cancel is tapped in the `MFMessageComposer`: **The keyboard for the `UITextView` is not shown anymore, even though the cursor blinks**.

I tried a few things, including a `[textView resignFirstRepsonder]` in both the button code and `-viewDidDisappear`. `[textView becomeFirstResponder]` in the `MFMessageComposeViewControllerDelegate` method or the `-viewDidAppear` didn't change anything either...

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't know, it's how Apple does it too (see the `MessageComposer` example)...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same issue, and was resigned to accepting fabian's solution, but found that by calling `[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO]` and then calling `[textView becomeFirstResponder]`, I was able to make the keyboard reappear. Something about the animation was screwing up the keyboard; looks like a bug in iOS 4.2.

Comment: At first I missed that that animated should be set to NO, but now it works for me as well.

Comment: I ran into exact same issue and setting Animated to NO solved it. Thanks for posting the answer.

Answer (score 1):

After the view has disappeared, you need to make your view first responder. Add the MFMessageComposeViewControllerDelegate protocol to your header, then use the following:

```
- (void)messageComposeViewController:(MFMessageComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MessageComposeResult)result{
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    [self becomeFirstResponder];
}
```

Happy coding,

Zane

Comment: Set a breakpoint inside the method and just double check that it's actually firing. If it is, then try adding another text field. Does your button respond to touches?

Comment: I already set a breakpoint in the delegate, it gets called. Also the button works, as the `MessageComposer` is shown.

Comment: That's a really odd issue. Try adding another text field somewhere else in the view and see if you can edit it.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and was able to fix it by calling becomeFirstResponder after a slight delay:

```
[textField performSelector:@selector(becomeFirstResponder) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.01];
```

Answer (score 1):

The delay trick also solves the problem of missing text cursor after showing an UIAlert right after MFMessageComposeViewController finishes, however the delay needs to be much longer (0.5 sec in my case)

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to find a better solution, so here is my fix:

In

```
- (void) actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet 
willDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
```

I dismiss the Keyboard and in

```
- (void) actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet 
didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex`
```

I present the `MFMessageComposeViewController`.

In

```
- (void)messageComposeViewController:(MFMessageComposeViewController *)controller 
             didFinishWithResult:(MessageComposeResult)result
```

I **don't** do `[textView becomeFirstResponder]` as it doesn't work. Neither does it work in `viewDidAppear:`. The user has to tap the `UITextField` again.

Not a very nice solution but the only one I found...

Answer (score 0):

As of iOS 5, here is one workaround. Before you present the MFMessageComposeViewController instance, resign first responder on your UITextView:

```
[self presentViewController:messageComposer animated:YES completion:NULL];
[textView resignFirstResponder];
```

Then in the delegate method `messageComposeViewController:didFinishWithResult:` do this:

```
[controller dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
  [textView performSelector:@selector(becomeFirstResponder) withObject:nil afterDelay:0];
}];
```

This fixed the disappearing keyboard problem for me. Without having to permanently dismiss the keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

This behaviour will not appear if viewController which is shown before modal VC is a child of navigation controller. So solution is to make fake UINavigationController and add your VC controller to nav controller.